# Typescript reduce acc with different key and values than input arg

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the error that property 'label' doesn't exist on type `Field` for below

```
interface Field {
  some_key: 'value';   
}

interface Fields {
  [key: string]: Field;
}

const myFunction = (fields: Fields) => {
  return Object.entries(fields).reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) => {
      return { label: 'label' }
    },
    {}
  );
};
```

Comment: `label` doesnt exist on type `Field`  Type `Field` has only one key, named `some_key`.  Since you're using `.reduce()`, the output of one call is passed into the next, so you can't return `{label: 'label'}`.  You'll have to return something like `{some_key: 'label'}`

Comment: yeah how do I fix it? I want to return a new object with just label

Comment: either change type `Field` to have a key of `label`, or change `return {label: 'label'}` to `return {some_key: 'label'}`.  Literally `"some_key"`, since that's the name of the key in type `Field`.

Comment: but I want to return something different, I don't want to return an object with `some_key`. I only want to return `{ label: 'label' }`

Comment: Does TS not accept using reduce to return something completely different than what was inputted?

Comment: correct.  it does not.  you would have to make a union type of an optional field on Field.  Like `interface Field { label?: string; some_key?: string}`, where `?` means "optional"

Comment: oh so I should use forEach then?

Comment: `.map()` may be best.  It lets you take one object and re-shape it.  So `[{a: "1"}, {a: "2"}].map((item) => { return {b: item.a}; });` would take something like `{a: "1"}` and make it into `{b: "1"}`. Note that if you do this, you've re-shaped the object so it is no longer of the original type.

Answer (score 0):

you can make optional field in the interface like this to make it work, ? marks the field as optional in typescript.

```
interface Field {
  some_key?: string;
  label?: string;   
  //... other fields either as required or optionals(use ? then)
}
```